# My Producer/Consumer C-Code is not giving any real output

Tags: c, producer-consumer

I've recently changed my OS from **Windows** to **NitruxOS**, and I'm currently struggling a bit with compiling my code.

I tried compiling with:

```
gcc main.c -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -pthread
```

but I'm not getting any real output; only the following warning:

```
*main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:29:44: warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]    29 |         pthread_create(&producer[i], NULL, (void*)producer, (void*)&num[i]);
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from main.c:4: /usr/include/pthread.h:200:15: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void *’   200 | void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ main.c:34:44: warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]    34 |         pthread_create(&consumer[i], NULL, (void*)consumer, (void *)&num[i]);
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from main.c:4: /usr/include/pthread.h:200:15: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void *’   200 | void *(*__start_routine) (void *),*
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define max 10
#define bufferlen 10

sem_t voll;
sem_t leer;
int input = 0;
int output = 0;
int buffer[bufferlen];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;



int main()
{
    pthread_t producer[bufferlen], consumer[bufferlen];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&voll, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&leer, 0, bufferlen);

    int num[max] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&producer[i], NULL, (void*)producer, (void*)&num[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&consumer[i], NULL, (void*)consumer, (void *)&num[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(producer[i], NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumer[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&leer);
    sem_destroy(&voll);

    return 0;
}

void *producer(void *pptr)
{
    int item = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&leer);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        buffer[input] = item;
        printf("Der Producer No. %d hat %d an Stelle %d eingefügt\n", *((int*)pptr), buffer[input], input);
        input = (input + 1) % bufferlen;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&voll);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *consumer(void *cptr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&voll);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        int item = buffer[output];
        printf("Der Consumer No. %d hat %d von Stelle %d entfernt\n", *((int*)cptr), item, output);
        output = (output + 1) % bufferlen;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&leer);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The identifiers "producer" and "consumer" are each defined twice. Once as an instance of an array of pthread_t and once as a function returning a void *.

Comment: ... and the functions `producer` and `consumer` aren't declared before the place to be used.